# Android - Scaling a custom map/imageview and keeping drawn marks in relative position

Tags: android, math, view, custom-component

Just to clearify....I dont think I can use google maps unless it will automatically scale custom Images I need to use when the map is zoomed.

Im trying to create my own custom view to use to display images of maps that will be zoomable and also allow the user to leave markers where they touch....maybe via longtouch with a single press or if I can manage it just via single touch.

How ever Im having a little trouble trying to figure where to start. So far I have a couple different implementations of zoom-able imageviews which work fine but I havent been able to come up with the math to allow the markers to move to their correct positions relative to the zoom level when a user pinches and zooms.

I have come across a similar solution to what I am trying to do on here before but of course now that Im looking for it, its no where to be found.

So my question is how would I go about mathematically figuring out where to draw my markers according to zoom level? Does any one know of any libraries or opensource projects that do such a thing already? Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a custom view again? Google maps android V2 lets you do exactly what you want.

Comment: I dont think that it will do what I want with a custom map image. These are going to be like the maps you see when you walk into a mall

Comment: problems solved? I encounter exactly the SAME question here.